# How to read a YAML file into a Hash

Tags: crystal-lang

I have a requirement to read a YAML config file from disk into memory as a Hash in Crystal. (I am aware of [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/crystal-lang/3TpVoSsrbco) discussion on the topic in the mailing list, although I find it a bit confusing.)

The YAML file I am trying to read is a fairly simple config file:

```
---
:excludes:
  - Stage
  - Class
  - Anchor
  - Notify
  - Node
  - /::/
:only_include: []
:md5sums: false
:class_name: null
:catalog_file: null
:output_file: spec/classes/init_spec.rb
:compile_test: true
:setup: {}
```

A code example showing how to read a YAML config file from disk into a Hash using Crystal 0.25 would be very helpful.

Comment: What does your yaml file look like? You might not need to read it as a Hash.

Comment: Who defined the requirement? If it was you, it would be better to describe your actual task.

Comment: I would expect that many people familiar with Ruby will want to know how to do this. If it's not easy, or recommended, in Crystal, I still would expect answers to this question to be of value. I am trying to rewrite this Ruby script in Crystal: https://github.com/alexharv074/create_specs/blob/master/create_specs.rb

Comment: I updated showing the content of the YAML config file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the best way to do it.

```rb
    require "yaml"

    class Config
      include YAML::Serializable

      @[YAML::Field(key: ":excludes")]
      property excludes : Array(String)

      @[YAML::Field(key: ":only_include")]
      property only_include : Array(String)

      @[YAML::Field(key: ":md5sums")]
      property md5sums : Bool

      @[YAML::Field(key: ":class_name")]
      property class_name : String?

      @[YAML::Field(key: ":catalog_file")]
      property catalog_file : String?

      @[YAML::Field(key: ":output_file")]
      property output_file : String

      @[YAML::Field(key: ":compile_test")]
      property compile_test : Bool

      @[YAML::Field(key: ":setup")]
      property setup : Hash(String, String)
    end

    yaml = <<-YAML
    :excludes:
      - Stage
      - Class
      - Anchor
      - Notify
      - Node
      - /::/
    :only_include: []
    :md5sums: false
    :class_name: null
    :catalog_file: null
    :output_file: spec/classes/init_spec.rb
    :compile_test: true
    :setup: {}
    YAML

    p Config.from_yaml(yaml)
```

Just note that YAML in Crystal currently does not support creating a Regex from YAML, so you'll probably want to do that after you parse it (it's a bit tricky with a converter).

Comment: Oh, I forgot about the field annotations. I think this would be easier if the Crystal YAML parser properly detected symbols.

Comment: Nope, symbols can't be created dynamically in Crystal.

Comment: That's very elegant. I assume the ? signs on lines 16 and 19 are typos?

Comment: No, they are the short form of `String | Nil`, since those fields could be `null` in the YAML config. It works with all types, eg. `Bool?` would be a nilable boolean.

Comment: @asterite I thought about treating them as strings and strip the leading colon, but that's a bad idea since it would change the keys when serializing back to yaml.

Comment: Actually, no, this doesn't really solve the problem. The script I am rewriting allows arbitrary data in through the `:setup` field, and not necessarily a `Hash(String, String)`. Likewise, it reads in arbitrary JSON data later. It seems like if there's no general solution to reading a file into a Hash, it just doesn't make sense to use Crystal for this problem.

Comment: You can use YAML::Any for the type of setup, which is effectively arbitrary data.

Comment: All of this is possible in Crystal. It's just that because Crystal is type safe and it seems your data and types are arbitrary, dealing with this is a bit tedious and involves a bit more code and type checks. Other answers are also valid, where just YAML.parse is invoked.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure, if this straightforward example will help you, but maybe it will give some hints:

```
yaml = File.open("conf.yml") { |file| YAML.parse(file) }
yaml.class                         # => YAML::Any
hash = yaml.as_h                   # As you can see below, it gives a Hash, but with YAML::Any underneath
hash.class                         # => Hash(YAML::Any, YAML::Any)
yaml[":excludes"].as_a.first       # => "Stage"
yaml[":md5sums"] == false          # => true
yaml[":output_file"].as_s + "-FOO" # => "spec/classes/init_spec.rb-FOO"
yaml[":setup"].as_h.class          # => Hash(YAML::Any, YAML::Any)
```

So, you need to keep in mind that YAML was the source of the data and not forget to convert it into required type with a `.as_*` method.

Comment: Unfortunately due to how the YAML is structured, this is the way to go. I thought about doing it with a Struct and the `YAML::Serializable` module, but it failed because of the symbol keys in the yaml and because `YAML::Serialzable` currently does not support reqular expressions (as in the `:exclude` key). I also had no idea what the schema of the `:setup` key is, since the ruby code just calls `awesome_inspect` on it.

Comment: Thanks very much. Would I make it easier for myself if I changed the YAML file to say JSON or some other format?

Comment: @AlexHarvey I'm pretty sure, it will change nothing for you, as you will just trade [YAML::Any](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.25.1/YAML/Any.html) for [JSON::Any](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.25.1/JSON/Any.html).

Comment: You could change the symbol keys to string keys, that way you wouldn't need the field annotation and could just write `property name : Type`.